# (Python) Text file into a list and setting the value as a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have this text file, and say it looks like this:

```
Top

Middle

Left

Right

Bottom
```

I want to obtain the last value `Bottom` and make it equal a variable (say `x`). How do I do this?

my code so far:

```
file = open("filename.txt", "r")
---> code that I need <---
if 'Bottom' == 'x':
 print("Correct")
```

Where x is the text from the file. Many Thanks :)

Comment: `'Bottom' == 'x'` is never going to be true; you're comparing literals.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: it's not exactly that, I'm comparing user inserted data and seeing if it is the same as the data from the text file

Comment: So you want to read the last line of the file?

Comment: Yes that's what i'm after thanks

Answer (score 1):

Split the read text by "\r\n" and then take the last element of the array:

```
file = open("filename.txt", "r"):
  lines = file.read().split("\r\n")
  x = lines[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

As アレックス stated, splitting the file into a list will get you on the right track.
But since you only need the last value, there's no need for a carriage return.
As that may not be the most efficient solution, this may help you.

```
bottom=open('yourfile.txt','r').read().split('\n')[-1]
```